# Python: how do I get the date from this date range 08/03/2020 to 08/03/2020 (excel equivalent of left( 08/03/2020 to 08/03/2020, 10))

Tags: python, excel

I have over 100 CSV files, whose date is saved in the following format:  08/03/2020 to 08/03/2020

I have the following code, but before append (or after) option I would like to fix date format (I only need first part), delete duplicate dates and sort dates chronologically. This is excel equivalent: left(cell,10)

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\AA2020\\files\\'

# Change directory
os.chdir(path)
# Define dataframe that will append the data to
df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    df_tmp = pd.read_csv(path + file, skiprows=range(1, 10))
    df_tmp.columns = ['value']
    date = df_tmp.loc['Date', 'value']
    count = df_tmp.loc['Results Found', 'value']
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[date, count]], columns=['date', 'count']))

df.to_excel(path + "results\\count.xlsx")
```

Comment: Do you have sample content from the CSV files you could share?

Comment: date                                        count
0 01/02/2020 to 01/02/2020 366                                                                                     yes consolidated excel has multiple data entries in the form above, which need to be sorted. I also need to delete duplicates

Comment: date count
0 01/02/2020 to 01/02/2020 366
0 01/11/2020 to 01/11/2020 266

Comment: To be more specific in my request, could you edit your question to add a snippet showing the first 6 lines of the CSV file? The comments you've provided are not sufficient to help me understand what your data looks like.